# Do we must define prepared statement variable in global, always?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have the function below for preparing and executing and returning result. i call it to prepare my insert query and bind a value to it and return executed result. but when i check number of affected rows in out scope of the function, it get me -1, however my expected record is inserted to my table.

```
function prepare_and_run($link,$query_structure){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$query_structure);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', 'a string value');
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if($result===false && !mysqli_errno($link)) 
        return true;
    return $result;
}
//call the function above
$link=mysqli_connect(...);
$result=prepare_and_run($link,"insert into table values(?)");
echo mysqli_affected_rows($link); // output: -1 !!!
```

I added 3 line to code and saw it is fixed:

```
$dpq_stmt=null;  // it is added
function prepare_and_run($link,$query_structure){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link,$query_structure);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', 'a string value');
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    global $dpq_stmt; // it is added
    $dpq_stmt=$stmt;  // it is added
    $result=mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if($result===false && !mysqli_errno($link)) 
        return true;
    return $result;
}
//call the function above
$link=mysqli_connect(...);
$result=prepare_and_run($link,"insert into ...");
echo mysqli_affected_rows($link); // output: 1 . it is correct
```

but why? Do we must define prepared statement variable in global, always?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very sure about PHP nor why your script worked by adding those lines but, to answer the general question, I think it's bad practice to declare your prepared statement as global vars.

Prepared statements usually need to be closed; not doing so can lead to memory leaks. Global variables are accessible for the whole scope of a module. While it may not be obvious for simple scripts, once your code blows up and needs to scale, it can get difficult to track which part of the code is using what global resource. This is a classic recipe for concurrency disaster.

Obviously, if you're code is *modularized enough*, you might really have to declare some prepared statements in some module as global. But when you do so, don't forget that you need to have a clean way to close those resources and that, when you declare them global, you're doing it not because you're being sloppy.

Answer (score 0):

kinda late but lets try to help:
If both the prepared statement and any variable binded into your prepared statement were not declared into the same scope then YES, you will need to use globals.

IF you don't do so these variables will be not visible by the prepared statement and it will be treated as a local vars - and it will be settle to NULL.